# $Broadcast and $on in angular.js not working

Tags: angularjs

//When i run below code nothing happen in browser i want to understand the //$broadcast and $on but the code is not working please help

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>
  var app = angular.module("myApp", [])
.controller("ParentCtrl", function firstCtrl($scope)
{
    $scope.$broadcast('someEvent', [1,2,3]);
})

.controller("ChildCtrl", function secondCtrl($scope)
{
    $scope.$on('someEvent', function(event, mass) { console.log(mass); });
});

 </script>
```

HTML

```
 <html>
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="ParentCtrl">
        <h2>Parent</h2>
         <label ng-model="mass"/></label>       
        <hr/>


        <div ng-controller="ChildCtrl">
            <h2>Child</h2>
        <label ng-model="mass"/></label>        
    </div>



</div>

</html>
```

Comment: My guess is the parent controller is created and the broadcast sent *before* the child controller is created and the listener added. Try wrapping the broadcast in `$timeout`, ie `$timeout(() => $scope.$broadcast('someEvent', [1,2,3]), 1000)`

Comment: you dont need broadcast for your synchronous code, just assign it to $scope variable and use it in child $scope

Answer (score 3):

`$broadcast` dispatches an event to all **registered** child $scope listeners.

In your example, `$broadcast` is invoked within ParentCtrl definition and the listener is registered in ChildCtrl definition. So by the time `$broadcast` is invoked there is no active listeners registered.

Invoke `$broadcast` after the listeners are registered on a button click.

Here is a working code for your example. https://plnkr.co/edit/GmA0GiLd5HVoykIi0FE4?p=info

Comment: @Kalyan..thanks for your response..but how can i do that without clicking Broadcast button OR how can i register child $scope so that it can have broadcasted value without clicking button.

Comment: @Kalyan..i have one more doubt ..why we need to write click function with $scope -       $scope.broadCasting = function()
{
    $scope.$emit('someEvent', [1,2,3]);
 }  why we can't write it like var broadCasting = function()
{
    $scope.$emit('someEvent', [1,2,3]);
 }